# CSS3 transition delays

Tags: css, css-transitions

Is there a way to set sequence transition delays through pure CSS.

in JS i would use something like a for loop and a counter to stagger the delay value. Can this be done in CSS with the

Also is there a way to set multiple properties on a transition shorthand. The example below shows just top when I try to put others it doesn't work.

Single property

```
 -moz-transition: top 0.3s ease-out 0s;
```

Multiple properties

```
 -moz-transition: top left bottom 0.3s ease-out 0s;
```

**The second question is less important that the first.**

Comment: "Can this be done in CSS with the" ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions here, but for question two, you can use the long hand versions instead:

```
-moz-transition-property: top, left, bottom;
-moz-transition-duration:0.3s
etc.
```

For question 1, it's not really clear what you are asking – you have realised you can set delays, so what are you looking to do that can't be solved by just adding a delay?

To be honest, you are extremely likely to have to use JS for anything more complex, as there is usually some logic required that can't be done in CSS.